# Unable to parse multipart form data at the server end

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I have a form data which I am getting from a mobile client. The server is a REST based server running in Tomcat.

```
@POST
@Path("/customerdetail")
@Consumes({"application/json","multipart/form-data","application/octet-stream"})
public String postCustomerDetails(InputStream message){ 

//CODE TO PRINT THE INPUT STREAM
       }
```

And the output of the print statement is below.

```
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobileNumber"

+14546645564
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="countryCode"

US
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="displayName"

fgfgfgd
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobileID"

AP4fdUS
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="emailid"

Rttyty@gg.com
```

What I am interested is fetching individual data. I mean I need data of `emailid, mobileID, displayName` individually and store it in DB as a string.

I am not able to find a suitable parser to do this. I googled a lot but not getting the exact solution as how to parse an inputstream which is a multipart data and access each data. I am looking for something like

```
String displayname=Obj.get(“displayName”)
```

Is this feasible?
Any information will be much helpful for me.

Comment: what version of jersey are you using? and does your "code to print the input stream" literally just print the input stream?

Comment: StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader bufferedReader;
 try {
  bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(message, "UTF-8"));
  String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
       while(line != null){
           inputStringBuilder.append(line);inputStringBuilder.append('\n');
           line = bufferedReader.readLine();
       }
       System.out.println(inputStringBuilder.toString());
       System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

Comment: I am using the above code to print the inputstream. The version of jersey client jar is 1.18.